# Identify running process that constantly use 5% CPU

Tags: performance

I have an instance of WP that use 5% constantly of CPU.

I try to identify that process, but when I run "top" command on my ubuntu, I can only tell that php7-fpm is the process which gives me this issue.

How can I tell which WP Process is running?

As I am in production, I can't disable plugins, to see how does it react...

Installed plugins:

```
AddToAny Share Buttons
Akismet
CodeStyling Localization
Contact Form 7
Desactivar Comentarios
Disqus Comment System
FastWP Shortcodes
FastWP WordPress Importer
Google Analytics by MonsterInsights
Logout Redirect
Límitador de intentos de login
OneLogin SAML SSO
PopupAlly
Post Tags and Categories for Pages
Simple Custom CSS
Slider Revolution
SlideShare
Top 10
Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
Use Google Libraries
User Role Editor
Wp Mail Bank
WP User Avatar
WPBakery Visual Composer
WPFront User Role Editor
Yoast SEO
```

I could disable Disqus, but still running at 5%, so it didn't resolved my issue...

Any idea how should I debug it?

Comment: Considering that WordPress scripts execute exclusively in the process of serving HTTP requests, it is highly improbable that WordPress is creating a constant load on your CPU. Additionally, plugins cannot execute in the context of a CLI application and supersede your server configuration's limitations without you having explicitly configured them to do so... If you still think it might be a plugin, replicate your installation in a development environment and disable plugins one by one. Otherwise, consider directing your question regarding debugging PHP CPU usage to [sf]